# Convergence of random sequences and their limits

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Suppose we have a sequence of random variables $\{X_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ defined on a probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P})$ where $\mathcal{F}=\sigma(X_n,n\in\mathbb{N})$. The $X_n$ not necessarily independent. Suppose I want to prove,for example, that $\mathbb{P}(X_n\longrightarrow 1)=0$. (where $1$ is assumed in the range of $X_n$). Should I prove that there is a r.v. $X$ such that $X_n\longrightarrow X$ at least in distribution, so that the claim to be proved can be clearly formulated as '$\mathbb{P}(X=1)=0$'?. In other words, while $(X=1)$ is $\mathcal{F}$-measurable, I am not sure necessarily $(X_n\longrightarrow 1)$ is. And we can only talk about measurable events. Am I correct in assuming that some level of stochastic convergence must be proved before tackling a similar question (it is an entirely hypothetical scenario, just checking matters of foundational character)?

Comment: But $\{X_n \rightarrow 1\}$ means precisely $\{ \lim_n X_n = 1\}$, which yet can be formulated (for example) as $\bigcap_{k \ge 1} \bigcup_{N \in \mathbb N} \bigcap_{n \ge N} \{|X_n-1| < \frac{1}{k}\}$, so $\{X_n \rightarrow 1\}$ is $\sigma(X_n : n \in \mathbb N)$ measurable. The trouble begins with stochastic processes indexed by uncoutable family of indices, but that is a different story.

Comment: Thank you very much, I see: as long as we can stay within the realm of countable intersections and unions of events in the sigma algebra, we are constructing events within it, by the properties of sigma algebras. Thanks again.